# XC8 Library organization and #defines across multiple source files

Tags: c, mplab, xc8

This is a complicated post so please be patient. I have tried to condense it as much as possible...

I am coming to XC8 from using a different tool chain for PIC microcontrollers. With the previous compiler, setting up and using my own libraries and using defines across those libraries *seems* to be much easier.

I want to write my own libraries of functions for re-use. I also want to store them all in a directory structure of my own choosing (this is so that they sync automatically between multiple machines and for various other reasons). Here is a simplified fictional file structure.

\projects\my_project       //the current project directory

\some_other_directory\my_library\comms_lib    //my communications library

\some_other_directory\my_library\adc_lib      //my ADC library

Now let’s say for arguments sake that each of my libraries needs the __XTAL_FREQ definition. The frequency will likely be different for each project.
Here are my questions:

1. What is the best/most efficient way to tell the compiler where my library files are located?
2. Short of adding __XTAL_FREQ to every header file how do I make the define available to all of them?
   Likely someone is going to say that it should be in a separate header file (let’s call it project_config.h). This file could then be located with each future project and changed accordingly. If the separate header file is the answer then question that follows is, how do I get the library headers (not in the same directory as the project) to reference the project_config.h file correctly for each new project?

Thanks in advance, Mark

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MPLABX, you could consider making one or more library projects for your libraries, which can then be included from other MPLABX projects.

As for a global definition of __XTAL_FREQ, I'm thinking that it should be possible to pass a symbol definition to the command line, not sure though.